# Whatsapp don't recognise deeplink, it’s not possible to tap on the link in the message

Tags: flutter, share, deep-linking

I want to share deeplink with parameter to the specific page in app through social apps. I use share_plus package.

```
Share.share(
  'Hello, I want to invite you to my new app. Click here: myapp://openapp?parameter=xxx',
  subject: 'Title'
);
```

Link is clickable when I'm using system Messages or Snapchat, but it doesn't work on Whatapp or Messenger.

Do you know any solution for that?

Comment: custom schemes are not supported by whatsapp or facebook. You need to give https schemes and configure the deeplinks or routing using unilinks.